# ¿como evitar que messsagebox abra otra ventana?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

tengo dificultades con tkinter y resulta que he creado una ventana root, que hereda a UI.

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkthemes import  themed_tk as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as tmb

class UI(Frame):
      def __init__(self,parent=None):
           Frame.__init__(self,parent)
           self.parent = parent
           self.parent = tk.ThemedTk()
           self.parent.set_theme("arc")
           self.parent.geometry("480x520")
           self.init_ui()
      def init_ui(self):
          self.parent.title("Nueva ventana heredada")
          ventana = ttk.Frame(self.parent)
          ventana.pack()
          entrada = ttk.Entry(ventana,text="ingresa")
          entrada.grid(row=2,column=2)
          #---------------------------------------------------
          def ver():
              try:
                res = int(entrada.get())
                print(res)
              except ValueError:
                    tmb.showwarning(title="error",message=" error")
          #-------------------------------------------------    
         boton = ttk.Button(ventana,text="pulsame", command=ver)
         boton.grid(row=2, column=3)        
if __name__== '__main__':
     root = Tk()
     sug = Label(root, text="aqui es para escribir")
     sug.pack()
     app = UI(parent=root)
     app.mainloop()
     root.destroy()
```

como pueden observar, cuando pulso el boton debe en la consola aparecer un numero, claro si es que lo escribiste, de lo contrario sale dos ventanas y una de esas es

```
tmb.showwarning(title="error",message=" error")
```

la otra es la ventana de root, yo quiero que no habra otra ventana y sospecho del tema que le he dado.

```
    self.parent = tk.ThemedTk()
    self.parent.set_theme("arc")
```

podrian ayudarme por favor?

Comment: ¿Estas usando el paquete ttkthemes?

Comment: si, asi es FJSevilla

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas efectivamente sobreescribiendo el padre de tu ventana en el inicializador de la clase UI.

Para usar ThemedTk, que es en realidad un wrapper sobre `tkinter.TK`,  deberías hacerlo al crear `root`, no en la clase UI, es decir hacer:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.ThemedTk()
    root.set_theme("arc")
    sug = tk.Label(root, text="aqui es para escribir")
    sug.pack()
    app = UI(parent=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

En todo caso personalmente prefiero usar la clase `ThemedStyle` en vez de `ThemedTk`. Recordar siempre que el tema solo será aplicado sobre widgets de ttk, no sobre los nativos de tkinter,

Tu código con algunos cambios podría ser:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as tmb
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

class UI(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UI,  self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        style = ThemedStyle(parent)
        style.set_theme("arc")
        self.parent.geometry("480x520")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.parent.title("Nueva ventana heredada")
        self.entrada = ttk.Entry(self, text="ingresa")
        self.entrada.grid(row=2, column=2) 
        boton = ttk.Button(self, text="pulsame", command=self.ver)
        boton.grid(row=2, column=3)
        self.pack()

    def ver(self):
        try:
            res = int(self.entrada.get())
            print(res)
        except ValueError:
            tmb.showwarning(title = "error", message = " error")

if __name__== '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk() 
    sug = tk.Label(root, text="aqui es para escribir")
    sug.pack()
    app = UI(parent=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Dos recomendaciones sobre buenas prácticas y cumplimiento de PEP-8, es importante no usar excepto casos muy justificados el modelo de importación `from módulo import *`, por otro lado es recomendable usar siempre 4 espacios por nivel de identación y evitar las tabulaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, de verdad te lo agradesco y en cuanto a tus recomendaciones lo tendre en cuenta